# Unable to resample then plot a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have been trying to plot a simple `resampled` data that is coming from a Pandas dataframe. Here is my initial code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Extra plotly bits
import plotly
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

date_today = datetime.now()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(56), freq='D')

np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': days, 'value': data})
```

When I do `print df` I get this:

```
                         date  value
0  2017-10-28 17:13:23.867396     29
1  2017-10-29 17:13:23.867396     56
2  2017-10-30 17:13:23.867396     82
3  2017-10-31 17:13:23.867396     13
4  2017-11-01 17:13:23.867396     35
5  2017-11-02 17:13:23.867396     53
6  2017-11-03 17:13:23.867396     25
7  2017-11-04 17:13:23.867396     23
8  2017-11-05 17:13:23.867396     21
9  2017-11-06 17:13:23.867396     12
10 2017-11-07 17:13:23.867396     15
...
48 2017-12-15 17:13:23.867396      1
49 2017-12-16 17:13:23.867396     88
50 2017-12-17 17:13:23.867396     94
51 2017-12-18 17:13:23.867396     48
52 2017-12-19 17:13:23.867396     26
53 2017-12-20 17:13:23.867396     65
54 2017-12-21 17:13:23.867396     53
55 2017-12-22 17:13:23.867396     54
56 2017-12-23 17:13:23.867396     76
```

And I can plot this easily (the red line in the example image below). However, the problems start when I attempt to create an extra data layer, which is a down-sampled version of the value/date relation, as in skipping every 5 days and and then plotting that.

For that, I create a sampled copy of my data frame with:

```
df_sampled = df.set_index('date').resample('5D').mean()
```

And when I do `print df_sampled`, I get:

```
                            value
date
2017-10-28 17:32:39.622881   43.0
2017-11-02 17:32:39.622881   26.8
2017-11-07 17:32:39.622881   26.6
2017-11-12 17:32:39.622881   59.4
2017-11-17 17:32:39.622881   66.8
2017-11-22 17:32:39.622881   33.6
2017-11-27 17:32:39.622881   27.8
2017-12-02 17:32:39.622881   64.4
2017-12-07 17:32:39.622881   43.2
2017-12-12 17:32:39.622881   64.4
2017-12-17 17:32:39.622881   57.2
2017-12-22 17:32:39.622881   65.0
```

And after that, I cannot really plot this anymore, the column seems to be broken. With the plotly:

```
    x = df_sampled['date'],
    y = df_sampled['value'],
```

I get this error:

```
File "interpolation.py", line 36, in <module>
    x = df_sampled['date'],
...
KeyError: 'date'
```

How can I fix this this. Basically, I am trying to create this image. Red line is my original data and the blue one is the down-sampled, and smoothed version.

[image]

**--- UPDATE ---**

The Answer provided below works, and I am getting the following result:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`date` is not column, but `index`, so need:

```
x = df_sampled.index
y = df_sampled['value']
```

Or create column from `index` by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df_sampled = df.set_index('date').resample('5D').mean().reset_index()
#alternative
#df_sampled = df.resample('5D', on='date').mean().reset_index()

x = df_sampled['date']
y = df_sampled['value']
```